# Touchpad moves/clicks on its own

Tags: mouse, touchpad, asus, 16.10

Recently I installed ubuntu 16.10 on my Asus zenbook flip UX360UA and everything works fine except for the touchpad. Whenever I stop moving the cursor for more than a few seconds, it starts to randomly click and move rapidly around the screen, resulting in some unwanted dragging, selecting and clicking. I can use a mouse with the USB port and disable the touchpad input to solve the problem but I'd like to see if someone had the same problem and found a solution.

Here is the output of `xinput` in a terminal:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ FTSC1000:00 2808:5120                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After touching my touchscreen (not touchpad) the problem seems to have disappeared. I apparently didn't think of touching the touchscreen before posting here.